# Regexp for match repetition of same word or part of it

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I give up: I simply can not find a solution to the problem.
I've already checked for hours on stack overflow site but I can not find a solution.
I have these strings:

```
table-2 table
table-4 seat
table-4 seat table-3
```

I want to use a regular expression to see if it already contains 'table-' or 'table' or 'tabl' or 'tab' ...

`(?).test(string) === true` only in Example N.2. How can I do that?

This was a attempt:

```
/\b([a-z(-0-9)?]+)\b(?=.*(\b)+)/g
```

Comment: show us what you have tried, we will help you from there, not just simply asking "how can i do?"

Comment: i tried like this: /\b([a-z(-0-9)?]+)\b(?=.*(\b)+)/g

Comment: @Helpme Explain some more what exactly you want the regex to find. Anything with "tab" or more is valid? Do capital letters matter? Do you expect needing line breaking, spacing or tabulation treatment? Stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

This code snipped passes your test criteria:

```
[
  'table-2 table',
  'table-4 seat',
  'table-4 seat table-3',
].forEach(word => {
  console.log(word, !/(tabl?e?\-?).*?\1/.test(word));
})
```

**UPDATE**
For the case if there is no exact word available (see comment below) it is possible to just check for some existence of some repeated substring that by itself forms a kind of word. In this case test may look like: `!/\b(\S+)\b.*?\1/.test(word)`, but of course exact solution may be different depending on actual task.

Comment: I can not use your code, because I have no fixed words in the reference phrase. Maybe must use '\w' ?

Comment: @Helpme well, this valuable information was missed from your original question

Comment: You can use `!/\b(\S+)\b.*?\1/.test(word)`, but it may not work in all cases